# Minimal spectral radius of a primitive matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the set of all primitive matrices of dimensions $m$ by $m$ that are non-negative and integer - which one is the matrix with the minimal spectral radius?

Edit (according to the first comment):

The matrix without the red '1' is an irreducible matrix with minimal (1) eigenvalue (in order to be irreducible it must have at least one '1' in each row). This matrix is not primitive, because of the locations of the '1's. In order to get a primitive matrix, we must add at least one '1'. The matrix below is indeed primitive with only one additional '1' (proof is needed...). Addition of more '1's will result in a larger spectral radius (for non negative matrices, $A \ge B$ implies $\rho(A) \ge \rho(B)$). The question is:
how do we know that this specific location of the red '1' will give the minimum?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to mention that we deal with non-negative integer matrices only (adjacency matrices).

Answer (score 2):

*(This is too long for a comment.)* I don't know the answer, but it follows from Perron-Frobenius theorem that if $A$ is a primitive matrix with integer entries, then its spectral radius must be bounded by its minimum row/column sum and maximum row/column sum. Therefore, I am convinced that the minimiser is a $0-1$ matrix with at most two nonzero entries on every column and every row. My own guess is that when $m\ge3$, the minimiser is given by the following:
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1&\color{red}{1}\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&\ddots&1\\ 1&&&&0},
$$
i.e. it is obtained by adding a $1$ to the $(1,3)$-th entry of a permutation matrix (in case $m=2$, use modulo arithmetic, i.e. add a $1$ to the $(1,1)$-th entry instead). When $m\to\infty$, we have $\rho(A)\to1$.

Comment: I too think that this matrix is indeed the minimiser. In the case of irreducible integer matrices I proved that $A$ without the red '1' is the minimiser, by achieving the lower row sum bound. However, in the case of primitive matrices, this bound is less helpful.

Comment: In addition, a matrix is primitive if and only if its period is '1', meaning that there must be at least one '1' on the diagonal.

Comment: @Rob No, a primitive matrix (like the one in my answer) does not necessarily have a $1$ on the diagonal. A matrix is primitive *if* it is irreducible, nonnegative and has a nonzero diagonal entry. Yet this is a sufficient condition, not a necessary condition.

Comment: Yes you are right, I meant that there must be a nomzero element on the diagonal.